# PowerEdge 2850 RAID 0 Configuration - Drive not found

Tags: raid, configuration, electrical-power

I have two 73GB 15,000RPM HDD in my PE2850 that I need to stripe as one logical drive so I can install MS SBS 2011 (which requires an 80GB volume minimum). I enabled RAID in the BIOS and paired the two drives as RAID 0 using the RAID configuration tool (Ctrl+M). However the Windows SBS 2011 installation tool does not recognize any attached drives.

I did 'Initialize' the drive, but the process only took 10 seconds so I'm not sure it processed correctly. Thank you.

Comment: I read in this post [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/127041/how-to-configure-scsi-hard-drives-and-raid-for-poweredge-2850-web-server) that Dell has a software utility to help with this process. I think I might need to update the RAID drivers. Do you know which software I would need?

Answer (score 2):

First: only do RAID 0 if you truly don't care about your data or downtime.

Second: SBS does not have the driver for your RAID card built it. Download it from the Dell site, put the .inf files in the root of a USB drive, and load it during the installation. After this, your logical volume will be detected.

Comment: Thank you for the concern with RAID 0. This is only a personal test machine and I'm not looking to spend money on a 300GB SCSI. The fault-tolerance concerns me, but I'll be okay.

I do remember seeing the interface asking for a disk driver during the SBS 2011 install. I'll get the data from Dell's website and try out loading it through USB. I'll let you know how that goes later tonight. Thank you.

Comment: Better yet - use one of these to install the OS, which will also install the PERC drivers (RAID controller) as well as any other driver that's needed - http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/poweredge-2850?driverId=R146318&osCode=WNET&fileId=2731115812&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM - http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/poweredge-2850?driverId=NF1CT&osCode=WNET&fileId=2731102793&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM

Comment: That second link looks like the utility I was originally looking for. I'll try that ISO out and see what happens. Thank you!